# Structure a Keras Tensorboard graph

Tags: keras, tensorboard

When I create a simple Keras Model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

and do a callback to Tensorboard

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='c:/temp/tensorboard/run1', histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_images=False)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=1, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

The output in Tensorboard looks like this:
[image]

In other words, it's a complete mess.

1. Is there anything I can do to make the graphs output look more structured?
2. How can I create histograms of weights with Keras and Tensorboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a name scope to group layers in your model using with `K.name_scope('name_scope')`.

Example:

```
with K.name_scope('CustomLayer'):
  # add first layer in new scope
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  # add a second fully connected layer
  x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
```

Thanks to 
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/4233#issuecomment-316954784

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Keras 2.0. I can't find name_sope in any Keras documentation. Do you have this working?

Comment: Apparently, with the latest version of keras this is no longer necessary.

Comment: You can use `with tensorflow.name_scope("..."):`, at least in the Keras API that ships with Tensorflow 1.4+.