# Group runs on the same graph in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

When running multiple logs at the same time, I can see the different training curves side-by-side in different graphs.

However I would like to:

- See all of the same kind of graph (e.g. loss) together on a single chart
- See the average and variance/spread of the runs on a single chart.

Thanks!

Comment: This may not be a direct answer, but one approach is to extract data from the event file using `tf.train.summary_iterator`, then make your own plot with that data. See this thread for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304461/tensorflow-importing-data-from-a-tensorboard-tfevent-file/37411543.

Answer (score 2):

#### Aggregate charts

If your runs are using the same summary tags (e.g. `tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)`) and are saving their events file in subdirs of the same root dir (e.g. `/model_results/run_1/`, `/model_results/run_2/`, ...), then by opening Tensorboard on the root dir (`tensorboard --logdir=/model_results/`) you should be able to see your plots aggregated by tags (at least for recent versions of Tensorboard).

#### Display average/variance over runs

This seems like a duplicate of [How to display the average of multiple runs on tensorboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068200/how-to-display-the-average-of-multiple-runs-on-tensorboard).  @Alex's solution there is quite thorough, using [`EventAccumulator`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/event_accumulator.py) to combine the scalar summaries over several files and `tf.Summary()` to write back the accumulated values (mean, variance, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while tuning a Keras model with tensorflow as backend.
You can check the issue and the code here: [How to use Keras TensorBoard callback for grid search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45454905/how-to-use-keras-tensorboard-callback-for-grid-search)