# How to plot loss vs epochs graph using .log file in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow, graph, keras

I have a training.log file which contain

epoch,acc,loss,val_acc,val_loss

0,0.3362708558291825,1.7554432798434318,0.32878239064221265,1.9248546749544395

1,0.44641053328276503,1.4846536312246443,0.4288102535608254,1.6995067473539371

2,0.48078999617260126,1.3865143429660396,0.5075229869044302,1.34374766792883

3,0.5082378348294684,1.315985157798793,0.5161604904205097,1.2767660616831913

4,0.5180953707906859,1.2740170841302745,0.5090554472080809,1.3178076734115036

5,0.5380194364147063,1.2369382053114344,0.5238227918972441,1.286055219077107

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple using pandas and pyplot :)

Here's some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt

# Create dataframe
file_name = "training.log"
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_name)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: @MushtaqPatel If it works, can you select this as the correct answer? It helps that people answer your future questions ;)

Comment: Perfect
This should be selected as the right answer

Answer (score 1):

1.Let tensorboard do the task of plotting by following below steps
Type below command in the set environment

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory
```

Once TensorBoard is running, navigate your web browser to **localhost:6006** to view the TensorBoard.You can generate log file just by mentioning the callback method in fit method while training your model. Mostly I prefer a tensorboard  way 
[keras callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/)
[How do I use the Tensorboard callback of Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112260/how-do-i-use-the-tensorboard-callback-of-keras)

2. Another way is access all parameters from the log file and use matplotlib 
   Read log file  and put appropriate values in below code snippet

   Plot the Loss Curves

   ```
   plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])
   plt.plot('access loss value from log file','r',linewidth=3.0)
   plt.plot('access val_loss from log file','b',linewidth=3.0)
   plt.legend(['Training loss', 'Validation Loss'],fontsize=18)
   plt.xlabel('Epochs ',fontsize=16)
   plt.ylabel('Loss',fontsize=16)
   plt.title('Loss Curves',fontsize=16)
   ```

Plot the Accuracy Curves

```
plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])
plt.plot('access acc value from log file','r',linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot('access val_acc from log file,'b',linewidth=3.0)
plt.legend(['Training Accuracy', 'Validation Accuracy'],fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Epochs ',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Accuracy',fontsize=16)
plt.title('Accuracy Curves',fontsize=16)
```

Comment: thanks,2) works for me but i don't know how to use tensorboard

Comment: @MushtaqPatel welcome I see ok I will add a couple of  links for your reference in my answer for tensorboard